# How to export data in a specific google drive folder?

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I would like to export images from Google Earth Engine in my Google Drive. In particular I want to save them in a folder that already exists in my drive named `Data`. This what I am doing:

```
  task = ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(image=image,
                              description=name,
                              folder='/Data/try/', 
                              region=geometry, 
                              scale=926.625433056, 
                              crs='epsg:4326')
  task.start()
```

Instead of saving the data in a subfolder of `Data` named `try`, it creates a new folder called '/Data/try/' as we can see in the following.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `Data/try/`?

Comment: Yes, it creates a folder called `Data/try/`

Answer (score 1):

Export to a Drive folder in Earth Engine is really not documented well (at all). Here's how it works:

If there already is a folder with the specified name in Drive, it will export to there. For this it doesn't matter if the folder name specified is in a subdirectory.

```
Export.image.toDrive({
    image: export_img,
    folder: "dir",
    fileNamePrefix: filename,
});
```

This will export to `/subdir/dir`. As you also discovered, if no folder called `dir` exists, a new folder with that name will be created at root (So `/dir`).

I don't know for sure what happens when there are two folders with the same name. As far as I could tell the file will be put into the folder which was last modified, but I am not entirely sure.

So in your case just use `folder: 'try'`. If you have another folder called `try` you might need to change the names a bit to get the result you want.

How it is right now, it is not possible to give a path to which Earth Engine should export the file.

Comment: you just copied another post and it does not answer to my question.

Comment: How does it not answer your question? (Also, it is my own post, only adjusted a bit to your question)